# How to get checkbox value from localStorage

Tags: javascript, php

There is a page with a lot of different checkbox questions which then get submitted and populate the next page, this page however gets refreshed and the already annoyed potential client needs to go back and fill out the form again. 
Now I have localstorage set up so he doesn't need to reselect all the checkbox again, he just needs to resubmit the form and his back in action.

How does one keep the values populated on the problem page so this fella doesn't have to go back to resubmit?

```js
//SIZE SAVE
function save() {
  localStorage.setItem('100', checkbox.checked);
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('100');
  localStorage.setItem('200', checkbox.checked);
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('200');

  //SIZE LOAD
  function load() {
    var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('100'));
    document.getElementById("100").checked = checked;
    var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('200'));
    document.getElementById("200").checked = checked;


    //THIS PAGE NEEDS THE CHECKMARK 
    echo get_site_url().
    "/the/checkmark/selected/was/".$_POST['check_group'].
    "/.png";
  }
```

Comment: `setItem('280')` ... `getItem('100')` you mixed id's and names in localStorage

Comment: Your save and load method is working right, you can check here in  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ooa5ahy/) 
Just check what @Nathan P. says...

Comment: Updated that Nathan, cheers, same issue though.

Comment: Do you get any error n the console ?

Comment: I guess the issue is when you save the values of your checkboxex with JavaScript to your local storage, you also have to read them with JS and apply it to your HTML, So you cannot use PHP for that, unless you pass the values to PHP via GET-parameters or something like that. BUt I still don't understand what exactly your problem is now?

Comment: Did you checked the fiddle? Check the checkbox and click in Save, uncheck and click in Load....

Answer (score 2):

I think is much simple for now and especially for the feature if you write some code to make the management for all checkboxes form your form.

First of all it will be best if you group all your checkboxes into a single place.

*Into a function like this you can declare all your checkbox selectors you want to save into the localStoarge (now you don't need to make variables for each selector into multiple places into your code)*

```
function getCheckboxItems() {
    return ['100', '200']
        .map(function(selector) {
            return {
                selector: selector,
                element: document.getElementById(selector)
            }`enter code here`
        });
}
```

Then to make things much simpler you can store all the values from the checkbox into a single object instead of save the result in multiple keys, in this way is much simpler to make management (let's say you want to erase all values or to update only a part)

*The following function will take as argument all checkbox items from the function above, the point is the function above will return an array with the checkbox id and the checkbox element, than you just reduce all that array into this function into an single object containing all the ids and values, after this you just store the object into the localStorage*

```
function serializeCheckboxes(elements) {
    var container = elements.reduce(function (accumulator, item) {
        accumulator[item.selector] = item.element.checked;
        return accumulator;
    }, {})

    localStorage.setItem('container', JSON.stringify(container));
}

function save() {
    var elements = getCheckboxItems();
    serializeCheckboxes(elements);
}
```

*After this you need another function who will read all the values from the localStorge and place them into your checkbox "checked" state*

```
function readCheckboxes() {
    var storage = localStorage.getItem('container'), //Your key
        container = (storage) ? JSON.parse(storage) : {};

    Object.keys(container).forEach(function(key) {
        var element = document.getElementById(key);

        if(element) {
            element.checked = container[key];
        }
    });
}
```

This is just a simple service who can manage your problem but I think, for any additional changes you can customize this solution much simpler instead of keeping all into multiple variables, also if you add more checkbox elements into your application with this solution you just add the corresponding id into the array from the first function.

A live example here:
https://jsbin.com/xejibihiso/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yes that makes more since in the long run. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` has two main functions, `getItem` and `setItem`. For `setItem` you pass in a key and a value. If you write to that key again, it will rewrite that value. So in your case, if a box is checked you would do

```
localStorage.setItem("checkbox_value", true)
```

and when it is unchecked you would pass in false instead. To get the value you can look at using jQuery like so:

```
$(checkbox).is(':checked')
```

and use a simple if-else clause to pass in true or false. then when you reload your page, on `$(document).ready()` you can get the values using

```
localStorage.getItem(key)
```

and use JavaScript to set the check boxes values.

`localStorage` only allows you to store strings. What you can do is use a loop to create a string that has all the check boxes values separated by some delimiter. So, for example, if there are four check boxes with values true false false true your string would be "true\nfalse\nfalse\ntrue" where \n is the delimiter. then you can store that string in `localStorage` and when you retrieve it you can put all the values into an array like so:

```
array = localStorage.getItem(key).split('\n').
```

Then you can populate your check boxes with that newly retrieved array. Ask if anything needs clarification.

Comment: Why not storing an entry for each checkbox ?

Comment: Thanks for the information i'm a little over my head hear but i have managed to populate the checkbox page, they remain populated after many refreshes, can't i use the same method to populate the next page (page that checkboxes post to)?

Comment: @OutlawBruce You want to access the local storage data from one page to another? As far as I know the local storage is only bound to the domain, so every page on your website should have access to the same local storage anyway!? So be careful when you have multiple pages and save some information with an id that can be used on more than one page.

Comment: @OutlawBruce Yes you can use any page using  localStorage.getItem(key).split('\n'); Before implementation first you need to check that key available or not in localstorage.

Comment: I would use $_POST['check_group'] to get value from the form on the previous page. what to use to get value from the localstorage?

Comment: @OutlawBruce  you need to pass your localStorage value to URL,and get it on PHP or use AJAX to post.

Comment: Okay maybe php would be easiest,,, but I'm not sure. Can you give an example of what it would look like for this case

Comment: @OutlawBruce window.location.href = window.location.href+"?local="+localStorage.getItem('check_group'));